# Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: permission denied: unknown

Tags: docker, mule

Getting error while running Mule Standalone server in docker desktop. Below is the Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM java:openjdk-8-jdk

RUN rm -rf Mule
RUN mkdir Mule

#Add  Mule runtime from our local system to the Docker container
CMD echo "--- Adding Mule4.2.0 runtime in Docker Container ---"
ADD  mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0.zip /Mule

#Adding Work Directory
CMD echo "--- Adding Work Directory ---"
WORKDIR /Mule

#Extract and install the Mule runtime in the container
CMD echo "--- Unzipping the added zip ---"
RUN         unzip mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0.zip && \
            rm mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0.zip
            
# Define volume mount points
VOLUME      ["/Mule/mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0/logs", "/Mule/mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0/apps", "/Mule/mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0/domains"]

#Check if Mule Licence installed
RUN ls -ltr mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0/conf/
CMD echo "------ Licence installed ! --------"

# Expose the necessary port ranges as required by the Mule Apps
EXPOSE      8081-8085
EXPOSE      9000
EXPOSE      9082

# Mule remote debugger
EXPOSE      5000

# Mule JMX port (must match Mule config file)
EXPOSE      1098

# Mule MMC agent port
EXPOSE      7777

# AMC agent port
EXPOSE      9997

# Start Mule runtime
CMD echo "--- Starting Mule runtime ---"
CMD         ["mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0/bin/mule"]
```

Building image is fine but while running it is giving error:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "mule-enterprise-standalone-4.2.0/bin/mule": permission denied: unknown.
```

Comment: Curious, why are you using 4.2.0 instead of 4.3.0, or even 4.2.2? And are you not applying cumulative patches?

Comment: I have my parent pom in 4.2.0... anyways even in 4.3.0 also I am getting the same response as permission denied

Comment: I asked unrelated to the issue, because using 4.2.0 misses all the fixes in later versions, and also the fixes in the cumulative patches. You are exposed to a lot of know issues already fixed. Of course, that has nothing to do with your docker issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the unzip command is not preserving the files attributes, so the execute attribute of the scripts is lost. Or maybe the file ownership is incorrect and it is executing with a different user than installed.

As a sidenote, MMC is not compatible with Mule 4 so you can remove that port.